# How do I Detect an EAN-13 +5 Supplement Barcode Using Python or NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to find a way to get the UPC plus the 5 number supplement barcode using Python or NodeJS.

So far I've tried using pyzbar in Python via this code.

```
 img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
 img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)
 results = decode(img)
```

That only returns the main UPC code. Not the supplemental code.

This is an example of an image I'm trying to read this from.

[image]

Comment: @DanBonachea Could you provide some more insight into this? I'm not sure what you mean by inappropriate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install the dependencies (on mac + python):

```
$ brew install zbar
$ pip install pyzbar
$ pip install opencv-python
```

You can define the symbols to ZBar. Please try this python code:

```py
import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
from pyzbar.wrapper import ZBarSymbol

img = cv2.imread('barcode.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray, [ZBarSymbol.EAN13, ZBarSymbol.EAN5])

for barcode in barcodes:
    print('{}: {}'.format(barcode.type, barcode.data))
```

I've tested it with this image:

[image]

The result is:

```
EAN5: b'07900'
EAN13: b'9791234567896'
```

(BTW, for your image this code scans just the EAN13 part. Maybe you have to use a bigger image, or increase the contrast)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I increased the contrast and added the specific symbols and I was able to identify the barcodes correctly!

Answer (score -1):

`pyzbar` can do it. You have to check if the barcode contains supplemental codes.

Try this (or modify the `img` part to suit your source:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

img = cv2.imread('barcode_image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray)

for barcode in barcodes:
    # Check if the barcode is an EAN-13 +5 supplement
    if barcode.type == 'EAN13' and len(barcode.data) == 18:
        # Decode the barcode
        ean13 = barcode.data[:13]
        ean13_5 = barcode.data[13:]
```

Comment: This does not work for the image above nor other images I've tried.